# How to build regression models and then compare their fits with data held out from the model training-testing?

Tags: r, modeling, r-caret

I have been building a couple different regression models using the caret package in R in order to make predictions about how fluorescent certain genetic sequences will become under certain experimental conditions.

I have followed the basic protocol of splitting my data into two sets: one "training-testing set" (80%) and one "hold-out set" (20%), the former of which would be utilized to build the models, and the latter would be used to test them in order to compare and pick the final model, based on metrics such as their R-squared and RMSE values. One such guide of the many I followed can be found here (http://www.kimberlycoffey.com/blog/2016/7/16/compare-multiple-caret-run-machine-learning-models).

However, I run into a block in that I do not know how to test and compare the different models based on how well they can predict the scores in the hold-out set. In the guide I linked to above, the author uses a `ConfusionMatrix` in order to calculate the specificity and accuracy for each model after building a `predict.train` object that applied the recently built models on the hold-out set of data (which is referred to as `test` in the link). However, `ConfusionMatrix` can only be applied to classification models, wherein the outcome (or response) is a categorical value (as far as my research has indicated. Please correct me if this is incorrect, as I have not been able to conclude without any doubt that this is the case).

I have found that the `resamples` method is capable of comparing multiple models against each other (source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/resamples), but it cannot take into account how the new models fit with the data that I excluded from the training-testing sessions.

I tried to create `predict` objects using the recently built models and hold-out data, then calculate Rsquared and RMSE values using caret's `R2` and `RMSE` methods. But I'm not sure if such an approach is best possible way for comparing and picking the best model.

At this point, I should note that all the model building methods I am using are based on linear regression, since I need to be able to extract the coefficients and apply them in a separate Python script.

Another option I considered was setting a threshold in my outcome, wherein any genetic sequence that had a fluorescence value over 100 was considered useful, while sequences scoring values under 100 were not. This would allow me utilize the `ConfusionMatrix`. But I'm not sure how I should implement this within my R code to make these two classes in my outcome variable. I'm further concerned that this approach might make it difficult to apply my regression models to other data and make predictions.

For what it's worth, each of the predictors is either an integer or a float, and have ranges that are not normally distributed.

Here is the code I thus far been using:

```
library(caret)

data <- read.table("mydata.csv")

sorted_Data<- data[order(data$fluorescence, decreasing= TRUE),]

splitprob <- 0.8

traintestindex <- createDataPartition(sorted_Data$fluorescence, p=splitprob, list=F)
holdoutset <- sorted_Data[-traintestindex,]
trainingset <- sorted_Data[traintestindex,]

traindata<- trainingset[c('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'fluorescence')]

cvCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number= 20, repeats = 20, verboseIter = FALSE)

modelglmStepAIC <- train(fluorescence~., traindata, method = "glmStepAIC", preProc = c("center","scale"), trControl = cvCtrl)

model_rlm <- train(fluorescence~., traindata, method = "rlm", preProc = c("center","scale"), trControl = cvCtrl)

pred_glmStepAIC<- predict.lm(modelglmStepAIC$finalModel, holdoutset)

pred_rlm<- predict.lm(model_rlm$finalModel, holdoutset)

glmStepAIC_r2<- R2(pred_glmStepAIC, holdoutset$fluorescence)
glmStepAIC_rmse<- RMSE(pred_glmStepAIC, holdoutset$fluorescence)

rlm_r2<- R2(pred_rlm, holdoutset$fluorescence)
rlm_rmse<- RMSE(pred_rlm, holdoutset$fluorescence)
```

Comment: Is there a programming question in there? Otherwise, this seems more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Consider the attention span of readers and reproducibility of an example as most important factors in getting a proper answer.

Comment: @Roland I posted here because I didn't know what code to implement in order to compare and pick my final models. I did not post to CrossValidated because they are very picky about questions that are focused on statistics and not so much the actual coding aspect. That being said, I might take this post down and put it up on CrossValidated if you think they might accept it.

Comment: @A.Val. Could you recommend me a way to make this question reproducible? I know about `set.seed(1)`, but I'm not sure which included data sets to use in order to make this code reproducible for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out-of-sample performance measures offered by Caret are RMSE, MAE and squared correlation between fitted and observed values (called R2). See more info here https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html

At least in time series regression context, RMSE is the standard measure for out-of-sample performance of regression models.

I would advise against discretising continuous outcome variable, because you are essentially throwing away information by discretising.

Comment: Nice, I completely missed out in the docs the existence of the method `postResample` that allows you to calculate Rsquared, RMSE, and MAE of a model with the hold out (i.e. testing) data. I can now take these numbers and even put them in a data frame for further comparison. Thank you!

Comment: @Otto Kässi Why is the squared correlation between predicted and observed values "confusingly called R2"? R2 is actually equivalent to the squared correlation of two vectors as shown in this proof (lemma1-3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901487/7769076

Comment: @AgileBean -- yes you are of course right! I have edited the answer accordingly. Thank you for your vigilance!