# Is there a function for coefficient of determination in R?

Tags: r

In sklearn there is a function `sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)` where I can give it two arrays and it calculates r^2.  Is there something similar in R?  I've found some functions but they are only for GLMs.  I have a test set and test predictions from KNN regression that I want to calculate r^2 for.  Am I going to have to hand-code this?

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40901445/4549682

One answer was this: `rsq <- function (x, y) cor(x, y) ^ 2` but some assumptions must be true for that to hold

Comment: Probably overkill but check package [hydroGOF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydroGOF/hydroGOF.pdf)

Comment: check out `caret::postResample`

Comment: postResample is the answer, thanks.  Why is it called 'resample' though, I don't think it's actually resampling, is it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)

Comment: also, postResample is using the correlation ^2 approximation, not the actual equation for r^2

Answer (score 1):

It is not something obvious, but the `caret` package has a function `postResample()` that will calculate "A vector of performance estimates" according to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/3.21/topics/postResample) (really helpful documentation).  The "performance estimates" are

- RMSE
- Rsquared
- mean absolute error (MAE)

and have to be accessed from the vector like this

```
library(caret)
vect1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
vect2 <- c(3, 2, 2)
res <- caret::postResample(vect1, vect2)
rsq <- res[2]
```

However, this is using the correlation squared approximation for r-squared.  Why they didn't just use the conventional 1-SSE/SST is beyond me.

The way to implement the normal [coefficient of determination equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions) is:

```
preds <- c(1, 2, 3)
actual <- c(2, 2, 4)
rss <- sum((preds - actual) ^ 2)
tss <- sum((actual - mean(actual)) ^ 2)
rsq <- 1 - rss/tss
```