# Unable to get R-squared for test dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to learn a bit about different types of regression and I am hacking my way through the code sample below.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)


# Polynomial degree 1
df=read.csv("C:\\path_here\\auto_mpg.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # Data from UCI
df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,as.numeric))

# Select key columns
df2 <- df1 %>% select(cylinder,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,year,mpg)
df3 <- df2[complete.cases(df2),]


smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(df3))
# Split as train and test sets
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df3)), size = smp_size)

train <- mtcars[train_ind, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_ind, ]


Rsquared <- function (x, y) cor(x, y) ^ 2


# Fit a model of degree 1
fit <- lm(mpg~. ,data=train)
rsquared1 <-Rsquared(fit,test$mpg)
sprintf("R-squared for Polynomial regression of degree 1 (auto_mpg.csv)  is : %f", rsquared1)
```

I am getting this error:

```
'Error in cor(x, y) : 'x' must be numeric'
```

I got the code samples from here (1.2b & 1.3a).

https://gigadom.wordpress.com/2017/10/06/practical-machine-learning-with-r-and-python-part-1/

The raw data is available here.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tvganesh/MachineLearning-RandPython/master/auto_mpg.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few minutes ago I got an upvote for [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901445/function-to-calculate-r2-r-squared-in-r/40901487#40901487). Now I guess it is from you, thanks.

`Rsquare` function expects two vectors, but you've passed in a model object `fit` (which is a list) and a vector `test$mpg`. I guess you want `predict(fit, newdata = test)` for its first argument here.

Comment: Yeah, I did that up-vote.  Well, your suggestion works, but hot to interpret the results?  Those can't be R-squared values.  Those numbers are way to high!

Comment: Exactly!  I'm seeing this: Mazda RX4 Wag = 20.20765 & Valiant = 19.38514 & 13.44487.

Comment: Well, what, exactly, does 'predict(fit, newdata = test)' do?

Comment: Ah!  Now it makes sense!  Ok, thanks for everything!!