# R squared as measure in Excel Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi-desktop

Is there a simple way to caclulate the R^2 value in a Power Pivot?
In 'normal' excel, we can use the RSQ function but that function doesn't exist among the Measure functions in Power Pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. There's no native DAX equivalent of the Excel RSQ function.

You could create DAX calculations to determine the Pearson correlation ([example](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/dax-query-language-for-power-bi-and-power-pivot/pearson-correlation-coefficient/)) or you could use R script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901445/function-to-calculate-r2-r-squared-in-r))

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the PowerBI method because I'm trying to accomplish this without using R.

Answer (score 2):

As @Olly says, there isn't a built-in equivalent but the formula is not too difficult to write yourself.

```
Correl =
VAR AvgX = AVERAGE ( Table1[x] )
VAR AvgY = AVERAGE ( Table1[y] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) * ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ),
        SQRT (
            SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) ^ 2 ) *
            SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ^ 2 )
        )
    )
```