# R-Squared measure in power pivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to add a DAX measure for R^2 in PowerPivot. I saw the [answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802291/r-squared-as-measure-in-excel-power-pivot)
and my current code is as follows:

```
=CALCULATE(
DIVIDE(
SUMX( 'Table'; ('Table'[Dates] - AVERAGE('Table'[Dates])  * 
 ('Table'[Daily Result ($)]) - AVERAGE('Table'[Daily Result ($)]) ) );
 (SQRT(SUMX( 'Table'; ('Table'[Dates]  - AVERAGE('Table'[Dates])) ^2 ) ) ) *
(SUMX('Tablw'; ('Table'[Daily Result ($)])- AVERAGE('Table'[Daily Result ($)]) ^2)))^2
)
```

X axis is a sequence of dates and Y axis is a sequence of values.
But this gives me nonsense values, sometimes well above one, while Excel's RSQ formula gives proper ones. How do I fix it/What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the formula I suggested in the answer linked? Yours is similar but tries to substitute the variables inside the CALCULATE and SUMX and also has some misplaced parentheses.

Comment: I did try that one, it still gives wildly different values than RSQ over the same data.

Comment: I’d expect it to be wildly different if tried it as written in your post. Separately, it would help to provide some example data and desired result in your question so that an answer can be verified.

Answer (score 0):

I give the formula for `Correl` in the linked post. You can either define this and write a new measure that references it, i.e.,

```
RSq = [Correl] ^ 2
```

Or else write a measure for `RSq` independently where you add a line to do the squaring

```
RSq =
VAR AvgX = AVERAGE ( Table1[x] )
VAR AvgY = AVERAGE ( Table1[y] )
VAR Correl =
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) * ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ),
        SQRT (
            SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) ^ 2 ) *
            SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ^ 2 )
        )
    )
RETURN
    Correl * Correl
```

Or you can square the numerator and denominator for a bit more efficient formula:

```
RSq = 
VAR AvgX = AVERAGE ( Table1[x] )
VAR AvgY = AVERAGE ( Table1[y] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) * ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ) ^ 2,
        SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[x] - AvgX ) ^ 2 ) *
        SUMX ( Table1, ( Table1[y] - AvgY ) ^ 2 )
    )
```