# Why do calculated residuals differ between R functions `lm()` and `lm.fit()`

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to switch from `lm()` to the faster `lm.fit()` in order to calculate r² values from large matrices faster.  (I don't think I can use `cor()`, per [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901445/function-to-calculate-r2-r-squared-in-r), when *x* is a matrix.)

Why do `lm()` and `lm.fit()` calculate different fitted values and residuals?

```r
set.seed(0)
x <- matrix(runif(50), 10)
y <- 1:10
lm(y ~ x)$residuals
lm.fit(x, y)$residuals
```

I wasn't able to penetrate the `lm()` source code to figure out what could be contributing to the difference...

Comment: `lm.fit(cbind(1,x), y)$residuals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?lm.fit` `x` "should be design matrix of dimension n * p", where `p` is the number of coefficients. You therefore have to pass a vector of ones for the intercept to get the same model.

Thus estimating

```
lm.fit(cbind(1,x), y)
```

will give the same parameters as

```
lm(y ~ x)
```